# How can I use Scala2.10+Play2.1+Jerkson?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, scala-2.10, jerkson

It seems Jerkson is no more available within Play2.1 (Scala 2.10) and I cannot find a solution on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play Framework 2.1.0+ uses Jackson behind the scenes, and is no longer based on Jerkson. There are no official ports of Jerkson for Scala 2.10, but you can try your luck with [this](https://github.com/randhindi/jerkson) fork.

Comment: I tried to check the fork, but I do not know how to include it into the project. Maybe there is a similar alternative to Jerkson. In fact, I need no more than a generate and a parse function, that's all. Nothing special. But I'm quite lost in documentation...

Comment: Then you don't need Jerkson at all. See "Parsing a JSON String" section in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson

Comment: As far as I understand, this requires me to tinker with JsObject, JsArray and so on. With Jerkson, for instance, I just had to do `generate(entry.attachments)` or `parse[List[Map[String, String]]](attachments)`, it was so easy. I do not see how I can get this done using Play's JSON functionality.